# Docker-compose build issue

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

I'm trying to do docker-compose build but the nginx return this error :

```
rm: cannot remove '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf': No such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'nginx' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Here's the docker-compose.yml and the Dockerfile as well:

```yaml
version: '3'
volumes:
  pgdata:
services:
  python:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/python/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=sphinx_django.settings.prod
    ports:
    - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: gunicorn -w 4 sphinx_django.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:8000
  db:
    image: postgres:10.3
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: '121211'
      POSTGRES_HOST: db
      POSTGRES_PASS: '55555'
    volumes:
    - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  nginx:
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: docker/nginx/Dockerfile
     restart: always
     ports:
       - 8080:80
     depends_on:
        - python
```

And the Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest
​
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
​
COPY ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

Comment: did you pull latest image? not able to reproduce the error, also is the `docker/nginx/Dockerfile` same one you posted above

Answer (score 1):

When copying your `Dockerfile`, I get:

```
Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 2: unknown instruction:
```

I think this is a problem with encoding. Try to convert your Dockerfile to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

[Context](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) is used to specify the location of build `Dockerfile`:

> **CONTEXT**:
>
> Either a path to a directory containing a Dockerfile, or a url
>   to a git repository.

From the structure of your project, `default.conf` located inside the same directory that your `Dockerfile` is in.

Your Dockerfile should be like this:

```
FROM nginx:latest
​
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
​
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```